# Change the default active version showing in dnvm list

Tags: dnvm

When I run dnvm list at the command prompt I see my default active version is rc1-update1 clr x86.

How do I change it to x64?

dnvm help shows that there is a command named "alias" which lists and manages aliases but it does not show how to set the default.

[Update] I tried

[image: the following]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute

```
dnvm alias default 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -arch x64 -r clr
```

to change the `default` alias. You can examine the content of the file `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\alias\default.txt`. Probably you would like to execute

```
dnvm use  1.0.0-rc1-update1 -r clr arch x64 -p
```

later to change the path too. You can use

```
dnvm upgrade -r clr -arch x64
```

to do all above plus downloading the latest released version.

Comment: the last command  worked.  I couldn't get the first command working though. I updated the question with my attempt.

Comment: @kirsteng: You can try `dnvm alias default 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -arch x64 -r clr` it should work too. The commend `dnvm help alias` displays the parameters which can be used in `dnvm alias`.

Comment: ah i left out the -arch

Comment: @kirsteng: It was *my* error during copy and paste the commands, which I executed in the command line before. In any way, it's good that the problem is solved now. Happy new year!

Comment: Thanks Oleg, Happy new year to you too :-)